# Please merge [dynamic-data] and [dynamicdata] tags on StackOverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Please merge [dynamic-data](/questions/tagged/dynamic-data) and [dynamicdata](/questions/tagged/dynamicdata) on StackOverflow.

Also, is there any significant difference between these tags and [asp.net-dynamic-data](/questions/tagged/asp.net-dynamic-data).

Comment: I have no idea the difference between the regular tag and the ASP.NET tag, but [tag:dynamicdata] is gone now.